# how to import txt files content in csv that contains the txt files name on each row

Tags: python

i found a datset online and would like to use it for a simple sentiment analaysis. however ive come across a problem. the dataset has over 1000 txt files and a csv document containing two columns,  the one column identifies a specific txt files name and the other column identifies whether the info within that txt file is hate speech or not hate speech.

for example say i have the text files with the name "2345.txt","2344.txt" and "456677.txt" the csv file will look like this:

| TXT FILE | LABEL |
| --- | --- |
| 2345 | HATE |
| 2344 | NOT HATE |
| 456677 | HATE |

how can i add the content of the txt file so the csv can look like this :

| TXT FILE | LABEL |
| --- | --- |
| I HATE EVERYONE | HATE |
| I LOVE YOU | NOT HATE |
| I DISLIKE THIS | HATE |

Comment: Locations of txt file and the csv file are the same?

Comment: yes it is. they are all in a file called "data".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, load your csv file using pandas as follows.

```
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file_name.csv)
```

Second, read txt file with loop.

```
txt_content = []
for txt_file in df["TXT FILE"]:
    with open("data/" + txt_file + ".txt") as f:
        txt_content.append(f.read())
```

Third, append the `txt_content` to `df`:

```
df['txt_content'] = txt_content
```

Done!

Comment: Okay. If the code does not work, add the comment with the error message.

Comment: it worked thank you so much!! I really appreciate it !!:)

Comment: Then accept and vote this answer, please :)